# Strategies For Naming Files For Download Via A Browser

Tags: file, download, naming-conventions, filenames

I am working on a site with a large number of (PDF) downloads. I need to come up with a strategy for naming these files.

So following are my main criteria:

1. Filenames need to be legal on all operating systems.
2. Filenames need to be URL safe.
3. Filenames need to be as readable as possible.

I've read around this subject a lot and read many conflicting opinions on what characters can and can't be used and what strategies are best.

**What is the best set of rules to apply to naming files so that they satisfy my three criteria above.**

I'm using Rails 3 for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe just about any ASCII character can be escaped in a URL (i.e. `%20` is a space).

The characters not allowed in Windows are `\/:*?"<>|` (according to Windows) and you can't have files with the same names but in different cases in the same directory (i.e. `FILE.txt` and `file.txt` classify as the same name). Linux and Mac are rather permitting. **All** operating systems or just those? There are quite a few less-known operating systems as well, but they're generally not for general-purpose usage.

So technically you can limit it to from a space (0x20) to a `~` (0x7E) in [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/): (with the exception of what's not allowable for Windows)

[image: ASCII]

But in terms of readability and if you don't want to escape URLs, it's probably easiest to restrict it to 0-9, A-Z and a-z and some sort of separator (like `_`) is always nice to have.

I found [this table](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html), which should give you a pretty good idea of what needs to be escaped for URLs:

```
Char    Escape Code
SPACE   %20
<       %3C
>       %3E
#       %23
%       %25
{       %7B
}       %7D
|       %7C
\       %5C
^       %5E
~       %7E
[       %5B
]       %5D
`       %60
;       %3B
/       %2F
?       %3F
:       %3A
@       %40
=       %3D
&       %26
$       %24
```